what does the combination of the present progressive tense and as of three hours ago mean?

The community is reviewing whether to reopen this question as of 3
hours ago.

What does it mean?
Did  reviewing  happen 3 hours ago? if so, why use present progressive tense? or is it happening?


I don't think it is a combination that anybody would say in normal speech. Here I guess it has been put together as a boiler-plate message.

what does as of mean in normal speech

Please do NOT post huge images like that. As of three hours ago, the community is etc.

The community is reviewing whether to reopen this question as of 3 hours ago.
So, starting as of three hours ago, the community is reviewing whether to reopen this question.
Better is:
As of three hours ago, the community is reviewing whether to reopen this question.
as of here = starting
I am eating my lunch as of [starting] three minutes ago.
The present perfect is not needed here.

I don't see it makes any difference whether the "temporal adverbial" phrase is fronted or not. It could "validly" be placed in several different positions. But imho as of just doesn't work without Present Perfect anyway.

@FumbleFingers They are in the process of reviewing in the present starting (as of) three hours ago. You don't need the PP necessarily. I'm eating my lunch as of three minutes ago.

I might add that as of is often used to mark a snapshot in time: "As of the time of printing, we still had no clear winner in the presidential race." Not since that time, but only known at that time. We might well have a different view now.

Is this question mostly a backdoor challenge to an earlier closing?

Collins Dictionary defines as of:

from (a specified time)

The reviewing was already ongoing three hours ago.   The present continuous tells us it was still in progress at the point this message was generated.

I don't find the cited text idiomatically valid.
Consider I have been dieting as of January. Maybe that's slightly unusual compared to I have been on a diet since January - but it's a perfectly valid thing to say (after January).
On the other hand, I am dieting as of January could only be idiomatic if uttered before January, as a statement of future intent. It might occur after January in "Indian English", but you can't couple Present Tense to as of [point in past time] in mainstream English. So the cited example should be...

The community has been reviewing whether to reopen this question as of 3 hours ago.

The reason for using a continuous verb form is that the review is still ongoing. For a "completed action", it would be...

The community reviewed whether to reopen this question 2 hours ago.


Grammatically speaking it is correct, it's just pretty awkward. If i had to guess this here is by stylistic choice. A sentence like "The stock market is fluctuating as of 2 minutes ago" is grammatically correct aswell, it just sounds weird but it is done intentionally, in order to highlight the current state of an ongoing action.

I'm not sure how you can justify claiming the actual cited text is "grammatically correct". Do you also endorse my example I am dieting as of January, which I believe more clearly shows why it's not valid? If you don't endorse that one, on what grounds do you say it's different? Bear in mind that syntactically, as of is precisely equivalent to and interchangeable with since in these contexts, but The stock market is fluctuating since 2 minutes ago sounds truly awful to me.

...what about I am starving hungry since I woke up? That's truly weird compared to I have been starving hungry ever since I woke up.

"as of" and "since" can't always be exchanged. "Since" can only be used with perfect tenses while "As of" can also be used in non-perfect tenses. That's why as of would be correct altough it sounds absolutely weird. If it would be present perfect continuous then you could also use since!

@FumbleFingers - but... Me: I'm a yankee-doodle-dandy! Friend: Since when? Me: Since yesterday, when my papers came though.

It is syntactically valid. He's working as of three hours ago. He has been working as of three hours ago. Both are valid. as of means starting. Of course, I am dieting as of January is also fine.  You can be doing something in the present starting (as of) some point in the past.

Some speakers use the present continuous rather elliptically to express both the inception and the currency of a  role  : I'm leading the tour since the first of this month which would mean something like "The decision was made on the first of the month to have me be the one to lead the tour and that remains the plan" Or to express the inception and currency of a  status: I'm dieting since the first of this month.  which would mean something ike "I made the decision to go on a diet on the first of this month and I'm still on it."

It states that it started 3 hours ago but is still ongoing. The focus here should be that it currently is ongoing but it started at the specific time (3h ago) in the past.
